# creation of store procedure in aws redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

While creating the store procedure to create the table in redshift, I am not able to create the table by concatenating with current date. could please help me anyone.

Here is my code :

```
create or replace procedure stud.studentlists()
as $$
declare get_date date;
begin
   execute 'CREATE TEMP TABLE stud.students_list_||"get_date" 
as
   select * from stud.students_list;
'
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You would use something like `execute 'CREATE TEMP TABLE xx' || get_date || ' as select...'` -- but what is the contents of `get_date`?

Comment: @john rotenstein, I want to concatenate the table name with current date. That is why I declared the date function as get_date.

Comment: I would think that `declare get_date date;` simply creates a variable called `get_date` that is of type `date`. Or is there something that automatically puts the current date into that variable? If you want to refer to the current date in Redshift, you can use `CURRENT_DATE`. You can probably use: `execute 'CREATE TEMP TABLE stud.students_list_' || CURRENT_DATE || ' AS SELECT ...'` However, it might need some conversion into TEXT.